# Почему не устанавливается модуль NumPy через miniconda?

Tags: python, cmd, numpy, conda

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Miniconda установил в папку *С:\Program1\miniconda*, но при переходе в командной строке по указанному адресу все равно такая же проблема

Comment: Похоже у вас miniconda неправильно установилась. Что возвращает `dir С:\Program1\miniconda\conda.exe` ?

Comment: @MaxU Файл не найден

Comment: попробуйте переустановить miniconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не в CMD нужно писать эту команду, а в Anaconda prompt.
Разница:

```
1 просто команда в CMD
2 команда в Anaconda Prompt
```

[image: Картинка]